# MarkLogic Technology Architecture and Monitoring combatibility with APM tools

Tags: marklogic

I am investigating monitoring solutions for a MarkLogic cluster and I had some questions about the technology architecture and support of APM tools.

Specifically I am interested in developingAPM or code-level monitoring of the MarkLogic Middle and Browser tiers.

https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/ref-arch/intro#

After reviewing the in the documentation, I was not able to identify what processes and technologies are utilized in the middle tier, or what defaults are used in the browser tier.

Are you able to advise what technologies are utilized in these tiers and if they are compatible with APM Monitoring solutions? Are they java processes or something else?

I am a APM / code-level monitoring specialist who is currently investigating the monitoring capabilities I will be able to utilize with MarkLogic application stacks.

A complete code-level solution will be able to provide me with detailed observability into the MarkLogic application.
Providing a exact metrics into the performance of the middle and database tiers by capturing detailed traces and calls.

Answer (score 2):

> Are you able to advise what technologies are utilized in these tiers

MarkLogic does not require the use of any specific technology in the middle tier or in the browser, so there is no set answer to this. For the middle tier, that could Java, Node.js, Python, or any other language able to send HTTP requests. It's worth noting that MarkLogic includes application server features, allowing that HTTP interface for queries and searches. Interaction between the middle tier and MarkLogic often uses the out-of-the-box REST API, but custom APIs may be built and used instead.

I'm not familiar with APM, but the recently-released MarkLogic 11 has [Enhanced Health Check Monitoring](https://docs.marklogic.com/11.0/guide/release-notes/en/new-features-in-marklogic-11/enhanced-health-check-monitoring.html), allowing monitoring tools to send HTTP requests to MarkLogic to check that it's happy.

There is also the [Management API](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/monitoring/intro), which [provides a variety of REST endpoints](https://docs.marklogic.com/REST/management) to fetch system and performance metrics. This is how other APM tools, such as [Datadog](https://www.datadoghq.com/blog/monitor-marklogic-with-datadog/), and [New Relic nri-flex agent](https://github.com/newrelic/nri-flex/blob/master/examples/marklogic-api-basic-auth-example.yml) integrate with MarkLogic.

Monitoring the middle tier will depend on the implementation approach taken by the development team building your MarkLogic-based application.